# Where is the data/policy stored in Open Policy Agent?

Tags: docker, open-policy-agent

I tried implementing the [HTTPS APIs](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/http-api-authorization/) section of the OPA. I was able to send the PUT & GET request and successfully receive response. Then I went through the shell of the container but wasn't able to find where exactly the data/policy is stored. Where is the data/policy stored in OPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, only in memory. See the [disk storage](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/misc-disk/) capability of recent OPA versions if you prefer storing on disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I actually wanted to know how can I see the exact location of the file in the Container / Pod. I logged in to the shell but was not able to find the exact location. Are there any other ways to get the file location?

Comment: Which file? Have you configured disk storage? If not, there isn’t going to be one.

Comment: Okay. I didn't configure disk storage.